# VS2015 Unit Test Framework shows failed tests as passing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I am writing tests using the Unit Test framework that comes with Visual Studio 2015. I keep a separate logger to log values and compare calculated values with expected values in the test cases. The problem is I have several tests failing. When they fail, I call Assert.Fail(), but the Test Explorer in Visual Studio still shows the tests as passing.

Has anyone seen this behavior and can you suggest what to do about it? Here is an example:

```
if (InitialFlatSocialCostFactorFromDB == CalculatedInitialFlatSocialCostFactor)
 {
     logger.WriteLine("InitialFlatSocialCostFactor (database): " + InitialFlatSocialCostFactorFromDB.ToString("F2"));
     logger.WriteLine("FlatSocialCostFactor (calculated): " + FlatSocialCostDeductionCalculated.ToString("F2"));
     logger.FinishTest(true);
     Assert.IsTrue(InitialFlatSocialCostFactorFromDB == CalculatedInitialFlatSocialCostFactor);
 }
 else
 {
     logger.WriteLine("InitialFlatSocialCostFactor (database): " + InitialFlatSocialCostFactorFromDB.ToString("F2"));
     logger.WriteLine("FlatSocialCostFactor (calculated): " + FlatSocialCostDeductionCalculated.ToString("F2"));
     logger.FinishTest(false);

     Assert.Fail("Expected Initial Flat Social Cost Factor does not match Initial Flat Social Cost Factor in database.");
 }
```

Comment: The default test framework doesn't allow for "parameter" based tests, but this (i'm assuming test) has branches in it.  How do you for a single test get and ensure you're in the correct fail branch that's reporting a pass?

Comment: it's usually better to avoid if's/multiple asserts in tests - might improve readability if you split that into 2 different tests (or one with 2 test cases)

Comment: Interesting, I thought it was a single point of verification - the InitialFlatSocialCostFactorFromDB as compared to the calculated one.